# Error in creating users in ASP.NET Web application after it was converted from a Web Site project

Tags: webforms, asp.net-4.0, membership-provider, sqlmembershipprovider

We used this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to convert our ASP.NET Internet web site that was developed using Visual Studio 2010. The application uses form authentication and it is an external website (not IntrAnet). The application uses SQL Membership Provider and it has built in 'Register' functionality - for registering users - that came with ASP.NET 2.0.

The membership functionality works fine after the web site project was converted to the Web Application project except for the following procedure where we get an error "type or namespace ProfileCommon could not be found". We did not get this error in the Web site project:

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   ProfileCommon p = (ProfileCommon)(ProfileCommon.Create(RegisterUser.UserName, true));
}
```

Please help. Thanks..Nam

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a Web application Project "WAP", Visual studio will not generate the `ProfileCommon` Class , and you need to access the properties through GetPropertyValue ...

Refer this link for more information: [The Differences in Profile between Web Application Projects (WAP) and website](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/04/12/the-differences-in-profile-between-web-application-projects-wap-and-website.aspx)